# installing vista ultimate 32

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

I currently have Vista Home Premium 32bit and want to install Vista Business 32 bit.  Is this upgrade possible without needing to do a clean install, meaning none of my software will be removed?

Hardware: Duo Core 2Ghz, 3GB RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This is possible if you have a disk from a retail package (non-OEM) or you purchase an [Anytime Upgrade](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/anytime-upgrade-overview.aspx) coupon.

Anytime Upgrade is by far the easiest way of doing this as it only takes a few minutes from start to finish. Alternatively, if you have the actual disk, you will need to do an upgrade install. The easiest way to do this is to put the disk in from within Windows and follow the on screen instructions.

If you already have the disks/coupons, go for it. If you don't and need to purchase them, I highly recommend you take this opportunity to switch to Windows 7 as the upgrade works well and it will be the same price, but performance should be better.

Comment: I'm in Europe, where do I purchase the Anytime Upgrade Coupon?

Comment: You can perform Anytime Upgrade thgrough the control panel - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Upgrade-to-another-edition-of-Windows-Vista. I also recommend upgrading to Windows 7 if possible.

Comment: Go to your favourite computer shop or look online at any price comparison website... Failing that, go straight to Microsoft - take a look at the link I provided and go to your countries Microsoft website.... Again, this is trouble free and the easy way to do it, but if you have to pay, I would recommend you take the opportunity to upgrade to 7.